# Print all permutations of possible outcomes given N rounds of RPS using a stack

Tags: algorithm, recursion, stack

Given n rounds, print all possible permutations to rock paper scissor using a stack as the main strategy.

I use to know how to do this, but I'm stump after not having exercise stacks for a while.

Can someone provide a helpful hint as to how the stack should be populated?

I know there are 3^n outputs for n input.

For n = 1, the expected answer is 3. A possible solution would be:

```
def rps(n)
  stack = []
  answer = []

  if n > 0
    stack.push([r,p,s])
    n -= 1

  while !stack.isEmpty()
    array = stack.pop();

    forEach elem in array
      // I still can't figure out where to go from here!!
```

I know in the recursive solution, it'll go r,p,s for n=1

for n=2, the answer gets appended with rr, rp, rs, pr, pp, ps, sr, sp, ss

for n=3, it'll be rrr, rrp, rrs, rpr, etc...

Comment: Can you add your current approach? It will be a good starting point for us.

Comment: I know I'm suppose to have a stack and a while loop. The stack starts off initially empty and I'm unsure what to push into the stack to start off.

Assuming n = 3, I'm unsure if I start off 

1. pushing []
2. pushing ['r','p',s']
3. concatenating ['r','p','s']
4. pushing 3

to the stack.

I know and have done the recursive solution, but it doesn't stick to me very well. I feel like I do it out of memorization instead of actually grasping the logic or developing a strong intuition.

Comment: If you have your code ready, it will be much easier to plug in and out the logic and explaination. If not, please add pseudo-code or similar in your question (not comment)

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go. To be honest, I feel like I'm at a road block. I'm not sure where to start, but I'll try to type out what I think.

Comment: Yup, please do, this helps to understand the question better. And can you give some example also? For example how a 4 rounds will work?

Comment: I know for 4 rounds, I'm going to have 3^4 outputs. In a recursive solution, I can just imagine a tree-like structure with 3 nodes on every level. I'd traverse down depth first and everytime I hit the bottom of the tree, I record the paths taken and plug that into an array.

I have no idea how to implement that using a stack though.

Comment: Can you be more specific, like what is the expected output for n = 3. And add that directly to the question, as it is hard to follow if you add it here.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, we can start with empty stack, and for each permutation pop out of the stack, we append all possibility to the permutation, and add it back to the stack.

```java
Stack s = new Stack();
s.add("");
ArrayList<String> result;
while(!s.isEmpty()){
    String v = s.pop();
    if(v.length() == n){//All n rounds finished, add to final result
       result.add(v);
       continue;
    }
    //Now, add the result of this round to the current permutation.

    s.push(v + "r");
    s.push(v + "s");
    s.push(v + "p");

}
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense now. I was way off in my approach. 

I see you just append 'r', 'p', and 's' to every element in the stack while the element does not reach a length of n. In the case of n=4, I can visualize 81 outputs and 81 + 27 + 9 + 3 pushes (which represents the tree I had in mind).

Comment: @beginner Glad that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I generalize this question to finding all permutations of numbers from 0 to N (in this case N is 3). One way to solve this is using recursion:

```
def rec(stack, used):
    if len(stack) == len(L):
        print stack
        i = stack.pop(-1)
        used[i] = 0
        return
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if used[i] == 0:
            stack.append(i)
            used[i] = 1
            rec(stack,used)
    if len(stack):
        i = stack.pop(-1)
        used [i] = 0
    else:
        return
N = 3
rec([],[0]*N,N)
```

What we do is we append the first unused item to our list and call the function again (backtracking). When our list is full print that list. This gives all of the possible permutations:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 0]
```

While this method is using a stack but I doubt that it was in fact the intention of the question.

The main idea of the question is **Implement a backtrack method to find all permutations of a list in an iterative method**. That's where the stack comes in.

We can simply imitate the recursive function by using a stack:

```
stack = [(0,1)]
used = [1,0,0]
N = 3

def iterative():
    while 1:
        if len(stack) == N:
            print [x[0] for x in stack]
            i,x = stack.pop(-1)
            used[i] = 0
            continue
        top = stack.pop(-1)
        index = top[1]
        for i in range(index,N):
            if used[i] == 0:
                stack.append( (top[0],i+1) )
                stack.append( (i,0) )
                used[i] = 1
                break
        else:
            used[top[0]] = 0
            if len(stack)==0:
                if top[0]+1 < N:
                    stack.append((top[0]+1,0))
                    used[top[0]+1] = 1
                else:
                    break
```

The only difference is recursive functions have some local variables within them that upon resume of their execution they remember them. We can put these local variables in our stack. In this case in addition to the actual item that we put in the list we remember from what value we shoud resume our checking (this is the variable of the `for` loop in the recursive function). This is what happens:

```
#[stack] [used]
[(0, 1)] [1, 0, 0]
[(0, 2), (1, 0)] [1, 1, 0]
[(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0)] [1, 1, 1]
A new permutation:  [0, 1, 2]
[(0, 2), (1, 3)] [1, 1, 0]
[(0, 2)] [1, 0, 0]
[(0, 3), (2, 0)] [1, 0, 1]
[(0, 3), (2, 2), (1, 0)] [1, 1, 1]
A new permutation:  [0, 2, 1]
[(0, 3), (2, 2)] [1, 0, 1]
[(0, 3)] [1, 0, 0]
[(1, 0)] [0, 1, 0]
[(1, 1), (0, 0)] [1, 1, 0]
[(1, 1), (0, 3), (2, 0)] [1, 1, 1]
A new permutation:  [1, 0, 2]
[(1, 1), (0, 3)] [1, 1, 0]
[(1, 1)] [0, 1, 0]
[(1, 3), (2, 0)] [0, 1, 1]
[(1, 3), (2, 1), (0, 0)] [1, 1, 1]
A new permutation:  [1, 2, 0]
[(1, 3), (2, 1)] [0, 1, 1]
[(1, 3)] [0, 1, 0]
[(2, 0)] [0, 0, 1]
[(2, 1), (0, 0)] [1, 0, 1]
[(2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0)] [1, 1, 1]
A new permutation:  [2, 0, 1]
[(2, 1), (0, 2)] [1, 0, 1]
[(2, 1)] [0, 0, 1]
[(2, 2), (1, 0)] [0, 1, 1]
[(2, 2), (1, 1), (0, 0)] [1, 1, 1]
A new permutation:  [2, 1, 0]
[(2, 2), (1, 1)] [0, 1, 1]
[(2, 2)] [0, 0, 1]
Finished
```